# Accessing seismographic data via fdsn with obspy (using network, station, location, channel)

Tags: python, obspy

I want to download seismographic data from the region around the vulcano Tungurahua. In the obspy documentation for the function [obspy.clients.fdsn](https://docs.obspy.org/packages/obspy.clients.fdsn.html) the steps for downloading data is described:

```
from obspy import UTCDateTime
t = UTCDateTime("2010-02-27T06:45:00.000")
st = client.get_waveforms("IU", "ANMO", "00", "LHZ", t, t + 60 * 60)
st.plot()
```

here the get_waveforms method has the arguments

- network = "IU"
- station = "ANMO"
- location = "00"
- channel = "LHZ"

with the function [client.get_stations](http://docs.obspy.org/archive/0.9.2/packages/autogen/obspy.fdsn.client.Client.get_stations.html) I found out the network and station name of interest in my case:

- network = "YO"
- station = "TBAG"

however I do not know the needed location / channel string to be passed to the function `get_waveforms`.

---

What I've tried:

```
client.get_stations(network="YO", station="TBAG")
```

which returns:

```
Inventory created at 2017-04-23T18:27:16.000000Z
    Created by: IRIS WEB SERVICE: fdsnws-station | version: 1.1.25
            http://service.iris.edu/fdsnws/station/1/query?station=TBAG&network...
    Sending institution: IRIS-DMC (IRIS-DMC)
    Contains:
        Networks (1):
            YO
        Stations (1):
            YO.TBAG (Banos, Tungurahua, Ecuador)
        Channels (0):
```

So it seems no channels exist. However when trying

```
client.get_stations(network="IU", station="ANMO")
```

I get

```
Inventory created at 2017-04-23T18:40:22.000000Z
    Created by: IRIS WEB SERVICE: fdsnws-station | version: 1.1.25
            http://service.iris.edu/fdsnws/station/1/query?station=ANMO&network...
    Sending institution: IRIS-DMC (IRIS-DMC)
    Contains:
        Networks (1):
            IU
        Stations (6):
            IU.ANMO (Albuquerque, New Mexico, USA)
            IU.ANMO (Albuquerque, New Mexico, USA)
            IU.ANMO (Albuquerque, New Mexico, USA)
            IU.ANMO (Albuquerque, New Mexico, USA)
            IU.ANMO (Albuquerque, New Mexico, USA)
            IU.ANMO (Albuquerque, New Mexico, USA)
        Channels (0):
```

So the channel "LHZ" is not listed here eventhough it obviously exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `level` parameter:

```
client.get_stations(network="YO", station="TBAG", level="channel")
```

You should then get:

```
Inventory created at 2017-05-09T12:58:29.000000Z
        Created by: IRIS WEB SERVICE: fdsnws-station | version: 1.1.25
                    http://service.iris.edu/fdsnws/station/1/query?format=xml&network=Y...
        Sending institution: IRIS-DMC (IRIS-DMC)
        Contains:
                Networks (1):
                        YO
                Stations (1):
                        YO.TBAG (Banos, Tungurahua, Ecuador)
                Channels (5):
                        YO.TBAG..HDF, YO.TBAG..HHZ, YO.TBAG..HHN, YO.TBAG..HHE, 
                        YO.TBAG..LOG
```

This parameter is described in [the documentation](https://docs.obspy.org/packages/autogen/obspy.clients.fdsn.client.Client.get_stations.html#obspy.clients.fdsn.client.Client.get_stations):

```
level (str)
    Specify the level of detail for the results (“network”, “station”, “channel”,
    “response”), e.g. specify “response” to get full information including
    instrument response for each channel.
```